# Where can I find Windows 98 drivers for VIA sound card VT8237A/VT8251?

Tags: windows-98, audio, driver

I'm looking to try and get a VIA sound card working in Windows 98. I have everything else running no problems, just the sound. I've tried everything I can think of including VIA’s website which lists this as available but when tried it's not compatible, alternatively the XP drivers work brilliant.
Hardware I'd from Linux, "Audio device: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller (rev 20)"

Comment: I wonder if there's some sort of backwards-compatible SoundBlaster16 mode you could use...

Answer (score 1):

I get a feeling it's not going to work. The VIA 8237 had AC'97 audio, but the 8237A has HD Audio (the successor standard to AC'97, which was published in 2004). To the best of my knowledge, there are no HD Audio drivers of any kind for Win98. If VIA says they have a download available, there's a good chance that they're mistakenly routing you to the AC'97 drivers for the 8237, and that's why those drivers don't work.

Comment: What steps would be needed to build a device driver? I realise this is probably not an easy task, but I'm willing to give it a shot, or is this just not worth it?